# After setting up admob my app crashes without error

Tags: android, admob, react-native

I set up admob using `npm i --save react-native-admob@next` and after that implemented of course in my XML file for android the right app-ID which was given to me by admob. I did it just like that:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-****************~*********"/>
```

Also I implemented into the app gradle file following line:
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'`

The last step I did was going into the nodemodules/react-native-admob/build.gradle and changing one line into this:
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0'`, before that the build was crashing.

My application now builds and doesnt give me ANY error message, however it closes directly after popping up and Im unable to do anything.

No error logs and nothing else beside that. Tried out several solutions which worked for people here, unluckily it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

same issue i faced with this plugin `react-native-admob@next`.
try this one `https://github.com/react-native-admob/admob`